# Docker start does not provide print output on the console

Tags: python, docker

If you build a container in docker from an image and start it with "docker run", my python script will run as usual and will also deliver the desired prints to the console.
But if I now start the same container with "docker start" again, I don't get any print outputs on the console.

So is it always necessary to build a new container from the image or am I currently missing one?

In the following I provide you with a short test python script:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
from absl import app, flags
from absl.flags import FLAGS

import include_files
from external_modules import external

flags.DEFINE_string("pa", "standard", "Testing")

def main(_argv):

    print("Python Version:")
    print(sys.version)

    print("Numpy Version:")
    print(np.version.version)

    print("hello world!")

    include_files._druck()
    external._druck()

    print(FLAGS.pa)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(main)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

Comment: In my experience, it's unusual to `docker start` an existing container, and much more common to `docker rm` the old container and `docker run` a new one.  (Also remember that you're occasionally forced to delete containers: if you need persistent data, make sure it's stored in a volume or otherwise is outside the container filesystem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you did not tell it to start in interactive session, so try `docker start -i`. Otherwise, you script may not be starting automatically when you run this command.

Comment: That is awesome, it works. And I have a second question. Is it possible to change the flag with a "docker start"-statement or should I build a new container with "docker run" and the new flag parameter?

Comment: I am sure you can change some flags, but you cannot open ports. So the answer is I know that some flags cannot be changed, but sure if all cannot be change, you will have to try those that you are interested in.

Comment: I tried to change the flag "pa" on line 9 with the follwoing command: docker start -i container_name --pa "foo".  But it says "unknown flag: --pa"

Comment: I haven't used that flag, you will need to read the official description of that flag.

Comment: Of course; `--pa` is not a valid Docker command-line option. Please ask a new question instead of piling on in comments; but search for a duplicate first.

Comment: @tripleee is it possible to change the flag of the script at that point of time?

Comment: Ask a new question, include your `Dockerfile` (ideally reduced to a [mre]).